# For set {a, b, c}, find equivalence relations

Tags: equivalence-relations

Why can't {(a,a)} be an equivalence relation for the set {a,b,c}?

{(a,a)} is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.

Answer (score 2):

It's not reflexive because it doesn't contain (b,b) and (c,c)

Comment: I believe you mean reflexive, not symmetric. The proposed relation is definitely symmetric.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer silly me, thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's not reflexive unless it contains $(x,x)$ for all $x \in\{a,b,c\}$.  It doesn't contain either $(b,b)$ or $(c,c)$ so it's not reflexive.

Comment: So it has to contain all elements from the original set but, it doesn't have to contain for e.g. (a,b), (b,a)?

Comment: @crt Right.  An equivalence relation is a generalization of $=$.  In that case, we may have $a=a, b=b, c=c$ but all other pairs are unequal.

Comment: Correct, in a sense. For a relation $R$ on a set $S$ to be reflexive, we do require that $(s,s) \in R$ for every single $s\in S$. However, symmetry doesn't have that same requisite: $R$ is symmetric when, **if** $(a,b) \in R$, **then** $(b,a) \in R$. This doesn't mean that every possible pair $(a,b)$ and its reversal $(b,a)$ have to be in there, only that if there is a pair $(a,b)$ in $R$, then so is its reversal $(b,a)$.